# Using PHP session when reloading a page

Tags: php, session

I'm using $_SESSION for the first time. I think I get the concept, but something isn't working. This is a page that need to load once with POST variables and then, when reloaded (to page through search results), remember the values of the post variables. The two variables would always be set or not set at the same tiem.

```
//submitted form variable definitions
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_set_cookie_params(3600,"/");
    session_start();
}

if (isset($POST['word'])) { $name=$_POST['word'];   
    $_SESSION['word'] = $name; };
if (isset($POST['exact'])) { $exact=$_POST['exact'];  
    $_SESSION['exact'] = $exact; };
```

Comment: use session_start() at the top of every page which uses $_SESSION variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your POST variables have a mistake. It should have an underscore `_` like follows.

```
isset($POST['word']) // change this
isset($_POST['word']) // to this

isset($POST['exact']) // change this
isset($_POST['exact']) // to this
```

Otherwise it will always return false.

It is also better to use `session_start();` at the top (It is not a problem here).

*To further elaborate:* `$_POST` is a [**superglobal**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). All except `$GLOBALS` require an underscore between `$` and the method used.

These superglobal variables are:

- $GLOBALS
- $_SERVER
- $_GET
- $_POST
- $_FILES
- $_COOKIE
- $_SESSION
- $_REQUEST
- $_ENV

as per the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php